# TypeError: arr.slice is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, image, upload

I get the error to draw some rectangles over the image upload in React-shape-editor library. It's said "arr.slice is not a function or its return value is not iterable"

My code is here:

```
function arrayReplace(arr, index, item) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1),
  ];
}
```

I have looked at a lot of fixing errors but don't know how to fix them. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is passed to the `arrayReplace` function as `arr`?

Answer (score 0):

The code works but only if you pass an array to the function. See working and breaking examples below.

Ensure that you are passing an array to the function.

Working:

```js
function arrayReplace(arr, index, item) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1),
  ];
}

console.log(arrayReplace([1,2], 1, 5))
```

Breaking:

```js
function arrayReplace(arr, index, item) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1),
  ];
}

console.log(arrayReplace({}, 1, 5))
```

Also note that passing a string will not break, so you may want to add some specific validation with a more helpful error message:

```js
function arrayReplace(arr, index, item) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return [
      ...arr.slice(0, index),
      ...(Array.isArray(item) ? item : [item]),
      ...arr.slice(index + 1),
    ];
  } else {
    console.error("[arrayReplace] `arr` must be an array.");
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log(arrayReplace({}, 1, 5))
```

Comment: Could you have a look my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/rectangles-ihsgo?file=/src/App.js? Look like I can upload an image but can not drag, draw or move the rectangle over the image uploaded